# How dynamically import multiple exports from module without knowing their values beforehand

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a set of SVG icons rendered as React components. Something like that:

```
 import { IconCancel } from 'icons';
```

I have backend endpoint that returns array of objects. Each object contains icon name.

Example of object:

```
{
  title: 'foo',
  icon: 'IconSubmit',
  // other properties...
}
```

I don't know what icons will be used until i fetch info from backend.

How can i dynamically import icons from icon module after i fetch info from backend?

Comment: Is that const supposed to be an import keyword?

Comment: yeah, it was a typo... Fixed, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamically import.

```js
const [listIcon, setListIcon] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    import('icons').then(res =>
        setListIcon(res)
        console.log(res)
    )
}, [])


const Component = listIcon[apiObject.icon]
return <Component />
```

Comment: That's correct but i don't want to import whole module: it weighs 15 mbs. 
My goal is to import only these icons that  will be returned from backed

Comment: Simple answer: You can't